# Proof concerning Mersenne primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, prime-numbers

Is this proof acceptable?

**Lemma**

Let $M_p = 2^p - 1$ with $p$ prime and $p>2$ , thus

If $M_p$ is prime then $3^{(M_p - 1)/2} \equiv -1 \pmod {M_p}$

**Proof**

Let $M_p$ be a prime, then by Euler's criterion:

$3^{(M_p - 1)/2} \equiv \left(\frac{3}{M_p}\right) \pmod {M_p}$ , where $\left(\frac{3}{M_p}\right)$ denotes Legendre symbol.

If $M_p$ is prime then $M_p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and therefore : $\left(\frac{M_p}{3}\right) = 1$

Since $M_p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ according to the law of quadratic reciprocity it follows that $\left(\frac{3}{M_p}\right) = -1$ .

Hence,  $3^{(M_p - 1)/2} \equiv -1 \pmod {M_p}$

Comment: It's correct. (and a few chracters to reach comment length).

Comment: However, it might be slightly simpler to use that $$(\frac{3}{p})=1 \Leftrightarrow p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod {12}$$

Answer (score 0):

As [S.C.B.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/310930/s-c-b) pointed out in the comments, your proof is correct. I've also edited the formatting of a few parts of your proof to make it more readable, take a look.

Comment: Quadratic reciprocity $\bmod 3$ takes 2 lines to prove.