# Pseudo-primality test for Mersenne numbers faster than Lucas-Lehmer test?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computational-mathematics, primality-test

**Definition**

Let $M_p=2^p-1$ with $p$ prime and $p>2$ .

**Lucas-Lehmer Test**

$M_p$ is prime if and only if $S_{p-2} \equiv 0 \pmod {M_p}$

where $S_{k+1}=S^2_{k}-2$ and $S_0=4$ .

**Pseudo-Primality Test**

If $M_p$ is prime then $3^{\frac{M_p-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \pmod {M_p}$

For proof see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1718453) question .

---

**Question**

Is this pseudo-primality test faster than Lucas-Lehmer test ?

---

My PARI/GP implementation of PPT (see below) is approximately $1.5$ times faster than  PARI/GP implementation of LLT .

```
LLT(p)=
{
my(s=Mod(4,2^p-1)); 
for(i=1,p-2, s=s^2-2); 
if(s==0,print("prime"),print("composite"))
}
```

---

```
PPT(p)=
{
M=2^p-1;
if(lift(Mod(3,M)^((M-1)/2))==M-1,print("probably prime"),print("composite"))
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean $S_{p-2}$ instead of $S_{n-2}$ ?

Comment: @Petter Thanks ! Fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both tests need about $p$ multiplications modulo $M_p$, so they should be equally fast.

The lift-command seems to improve the calculation of large powers modulo large numbers, probably the reason PARI/GP is faster using this method.

The disadvantage of the pseudoprime-test is, of course, that the result is not $100$% correct, in contrary to the Lucas-Lehmer-Test.

Comment: Are there any known counterexamples, i.e. primes $p$ such that $3^{(M_p-1)/2} \equiv 1 \pmod{M_p}$ but $M_p$ is not prime?

Comment: @DaveRadcliffe I think this is unknown.